# How to get the window handle for a form and its child window handles in c#

Tags: c#

In my c# application I want window handle for a form.I know the ".exe" name of the window , so i tried "GetProcessesByName" function . I got the the handle of the application but do not know how to get the child windows for it. Guide me

```
Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess");

foreach (Process p1 in p)
{
    MessageBox.Show(GetWindowText(p1.MainWindowHandle));
}
```

Using the handle `p1`, I need to get the child window handles of `p1`. How to do it?

Comment: Use [System.Windows.Automation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160314-00/?p=93152).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I achieved this using couple of functions such as "**GetProcessesByName**" to get the handle of main window and "**EnumChildWindows**" to get the handle of child windows.Refer below for source code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using Microsoft.Win32;

[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle,     Win32Callback callback, IntPtr lParam);

Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("StikyNot"); //this is for sticky notes
foreach (Process p1 in p)
        {                
            IntPtr MainWindowHandle = p1.MainWindowHandle;              

            List<IntPtr> GetChildWindowsHandle=GetChildWindows(MainWindowHandle);
        }

 public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            Win32Callback childProc = new Win32Callback(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }
```